# Can't download or find the TFRecord I generated in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, tfrecord

I am kind of newbie in colab and TFRecord. I am trying to write a TFRecord file on my google drive. I could successfully write it in the location where I want and I have checked it in the notebook (both on the sidebar and under command '%ls -lta'). I also could parse and read the TFRecord I just generated in the same notebook. But when I checked the google drive, I couldn't find it and can't download from the sidebar neither. If anyone experiences same issue, could you tell me how to fix it?

I would be extremely appreciated!

Best,
ZY[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQLZ.png)

I have tried to download the TFRecord file from sidebar in the notebook and I couldn't. Also, I have tried use all kinds of advanced research in the google drive to find thee TFRecord file.